# Content Zero of Discontinuities Gives Integrable Function

Tags: integration, continuity

Suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a bounded function and $D$ is the set of discontinuities of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

How can we show that if $D$ has content zero, then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$?

The textbook I am using defines content zero to be a set such that for any $\epsilon$, we can find a set of open intervals with total length less than $\epsilon$ whose union contains the set.

I am not familiar with the Lebesgue criteria so I would prefer an answer that does not use it.

Comment: By content, do you mean measure?

Comment: No, I believe this specifically applies to content zero (the concept is similar to measure but you can only use finitely many intervals)

Comment: In that case you have to specify which content you are using, and by which measure you are evaluating integrability.

Comment: @jMdA It should be more clear now?

Comment: You also have to assume boundedness of $f$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right, I've edited to clarify that, thank you.

Comment: *we can find a set of open intervals with* --- I think you should say "we can find a finite set of open intervals with". Also, you should specify what definition you're using for "Riemann integrable" (there is more than one way that this is defined in textbooks), or at least specify exactly the textbook this is from. That said, this is a fundamental result that is usually a major proved-theorem in textbooks that cover theoretical aspects of Riemann integration, and proofs are not very concise. I suspect your particular textbook has already laid quite a bit of "groundwork" for such a proof.